# Gulp Error - ReferenceError: js is not defined

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am learning gulp and write at the moment my first tasks. I got this task:

```
gulp.task('js-libs', function () {
    return gulp.src([
        // Add JavaScript Files here
        './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
    ])
        // Output for Angular Files
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js/'))
        .on('error', js-libs.logError);
});
```

And when i run it, i get this error in terminal:

```
$ gulp js-libs
[01:02:41] Using gulpfile ~\PhpstormProjects\xxx\gulpfile.js
[01:02:41] Starting 'js-libs'...
[01:02:41] 'js-libs' errored after 7.28 ms
[01:02:41] ReferenceError: js is not defined
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxx\PhpstormProjects\xxx\gulp\javascript.js:27:22)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\xxx\PhpstormProjects\xxx\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (C:\Users\xxx\PhpstormProjects\xxx\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (C:\Users\xxx\PhpstormProjects\xxx\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (C:\Users\xxx\PhpstormProjects\xxx\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
    at C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129:20
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:443:11)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
```

So now is the big question... What is wrong? The script works correct... It take the js files and put them out where i want. But why i get this error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based upon the snipped you posted, the error message is showing you the line and the exact error:

```
js-libs.logError
```

This is looking for a variable called `js` and is trying to subtract `libs.logError`.

Comment: So names with "-" are not allowed?
When i rename the taskname into jsLibs then i get another error... throw new Error('Task requires a name');

Comment: Correct `-` is not allowed as an identifier.  They start with a letter and then can contain only letters, numbers, the underscore or the dollar sign.  As for the second part, if you have a new question ask a new question.. or try googling for that phrase and see if any hints come up.